# How Can I setup a local DB and Connect it to my index.html file I created for use on my laptop

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I create a database for local use only to keep track of my inventory. I want the data I enter into the HTML5/CSS3/JS form I already created to be stored away the form has

ItemName:________________ 
InventoryID:_____________ 
Date:____________________ 
Checkbox: ___________

And other things to fill out, this is just an example, and finally a submit button.

I was thinking can I use Microsoft Access, MySQL WorkBench, or what's the best approach, I'm a total noob.

Thanks, all and every help is appreciated.

Comment: Any and all of them will work fine. If you pick one and try to write code and have a very specific question about your code you should come back and ask about that.

Comment: You can use any of them it's all fine, please do some code work and then edit your question with some work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can download XAMPP here https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html. Xampp involves Apache which works as a local server in your PC , PHP and Mysql where you can create a database on your own.